# Can I work remotely in Germany on a Schengen short-stay visa?

Tags: visas, europe

I am working on an H-1B visa in the US and hold an Indian passport. I am planning to travel to Schengen countries this summer. My company has an office in Germany, and I am planning to work remotely for 3 weeks and then travel for 3 weeks. Can I combine work and vacation on a Schengen Visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. Working remotely **from** Germany means working **in** Germany, and if that isn't covered by the activities permitted by a business visa, you need a work permit to do so.

- You did not state your nationality. I'm assuming that you're **not** an EU/EEA citizen, or you wouldn't have a visa.
- Depending on your employer, you might qualify for a work permit as an intra-company transfer. For that, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.
- Your visa may explicitly permit you to work. That isn't normal.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Can I combine my vacation during this period on my business visa?

Comment: @3xplore, you can combinde different activities which are allowed on a C visa. I'm still not sure if what you propose to do is allowed on a C.